# Show / Hide em um form quando clicar em um input radio

Tags: jquery, html5

Fiz um código que por algum motivo não está funcionando ele deve funcionar da seguinte maneira.

Quando eu clicar no `input radio` p**essoa juridica** ele deve abrir o form de **pessoa juridica** e quando eu clicar em **pessoa fisica** deve esconder o form de **pessoa juridica** e exibir o de **pessoa fisica** lembrando que por padrão o form **de pessoa fisica** deve ficar aparecendo segue meu código

HTML:

```
<div class="bs-example mb-3 text-center">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                            <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="bn" value="1" id="pessoaFisica" checked="checked">
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="pessoaFisica">Pessoa Física</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                            <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="bn" value="2" id="pessoaJuridica">
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="pessoaJuridica">Pessoa Juridica</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

<form class="form-register-pessoa-fisica" id="fisica" >
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Nome completo</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-dark-search-little -gray-medium" name="email" id="no" placeholder="Nome completo">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Informe seu e-mail</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-dark-search-little -gray-medium" name="email" id="no" placeholder="Digite seu e-mail">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Digite sua senha</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control input-dark-search-little -gray-medium" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Confirmar sua senha</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control input-dark-search-little -gray-medium" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <a href="login.php" class="forgot-passoword">Voltar</a>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn-default-gradient">Cadastrar</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>


<form class="form-register-pessoa-fisica" id="juridica" >
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Nome completo</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-dark-search-little -gray-medium" name="email" id="no" placeholder="Nome completo">
                    </div>
                </form>
```

JS:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("input[name$='bn']").click(function(){
                var radio_value = $(this).val();
                if(radio_value=='0') {
                    $("#fisica").hide("slow");
                    $("#juridica").hide("slow");
                }
                else if(radio_value=='1') {
                    $("#fisica").show("slow");
                    $("#juridica").hide("slow");
                }
                else if(radio_value=='2') {
                    $("#fisica").show("slow");
                    $("#juridica").hide("slow");
                }
            });
            $('[name="bn"]:checked').trigger('click');
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Segue:

```
         $("input[name$='bn']").click(function(){
                var radio_value = $(this).val();
                if(radio_value=='0') {
                    $("#fisica").hide("slow");
                    $("#juridica").hide("slow");
                }
                else if(radio_value=='1') {
                    $("#fisica").show("slow");
                    $("#juridica").hide("slow");
                }
                else if(radio_value=='2') {
                    $("#fisica").hide("slow");
                    $("#juridica").show("slow");
                }
            });
            $('[name="bn"]:checked').trigger('click');
        });
```

Comment: Ian, seria interessante criar uma resposta mais completa, explicando o que faz cada trecho do código postado.

Answer (score 0):

```
else if(radio_value=='2') {
  $("#fisica").show("slow");
  $("#juridica").hide("slow");
}
```

Nesta linha você esqueceu de trocar o nome da função, fazendo com que a #fisica fique como show() e a #juridica fique como hide() independente se o radio_value for 1 ou 2. Você terá que trocar as funções, vai ficar assim:

```
else if(radio_value=='2') {
  $("#fisica").hide("slow");
  $("#juridica").show("slow");
}
```